# What are the steps to read an object from an ADO.net data service?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, wcf-data-services

I'm new to ADO.net data services (and to .net in general too..), I'm having this project where I need to setup a data service to read and write to a database with nHibernate, I've created the service:

```
[WebGet]
    [SingleResult]
    public Factory Factories(int Id)
    {
        try
        {
            Factory[] results = this.CurrentDataSource.Session.Linq<Factory>().Where(g => g.Id.Equals(Id)).ToArray();
            return results[0];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

And I've created a test for the service:

```
[Test]
        public void CanReadFactoryDataService()
        {
            DataServiceContext ctx = new
                  DataServiceContext(new Uri("http://localhost:1413/DataService.svc"));
            var Factories = ctx.Execute<Factory>(
                  new Uri("Factories?Id=54", UriKind.Relative));
            Assert.IsNotNull(Factories);
            Factory factory = Factories.First<Factory>();
            {
                Console.WriteLine(factory.NAME);
            }
```

When I run the service with the browser (eg: http://localhost:1413/DataService.svc/Factories?Id=54), the service returns:

```
<Factories p1:type="ADODS.Core.Factory">
<FactorY_CODE>abc</FactorY_CODE>
<NAME>Nameds</NAME>
<ADDRESS>Reinhardt strasse</ADDRESS>
<COMPENSATION_MODEL p1:null="true"/>
<B_CODE p1:null="true"/>
<Id p1:type="Edm.Int32">54</Id>
</Factories>
```

But when I run the unit test I'm getting this exception:

```
TestCase 'Tests.DataServicesTests.CanReadFactoryDataService'
failed: System.InvalidOperationException : La secuencia no contiene elementos (The sequence contains no elements)
    en System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
    H:\ADODS\tests\ADODS.Tests\ADODS.Web\DataServicesTests.cs(22,0): en Tests.DataServicesTests.CanReadFactoryDataService()
```

I debugged the project, so the test connects to the service and the service returns the data, but

**is there anything else I should do to convert the xml data into the actual object when I receive it?**

I did a test, with a `string` object instead of a `Factory` and it worked, the problem seems to be with my classes. **Am I missing something?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it:
I Added a Service reference (Wich I hadn't done), and changed the test to:

```
[Test]
        public void CanReadFactoryDataService()
        {
            ServiceReference1.DataServiceContext ctx = new
                   ServiceReference1.DataServiceContext(new Uri("http://localhost:1413/DataService.svc"));
            var factories= ctx.Execute<Factory>(
                  new Uri("Factories?Id=54", UriKind.Relative));
            Assert.IsNotNull(factories);
            Factory factory = factories.First<Factory>();
            {
                Console.WriteLine(factory.ADDRESS);
            }

        }
```

And now it passes the test:

```
Reinhardt strasse

1 passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, took 3.48 seconds (NUnit 2.5.2).
```

Now I think that was easy, but when you don't know, it's hard...